# Why google material design says: "Material never bends or folds."

Tags: android, material-design

I read from [material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/material-properties.html#material-properties-transforming-material) that material never bends or folds. But why? While it is so interesting, delightful and a really nice animation specially in reading books apps?

What's its problem?

Thanks

Comment: They don't like it. It does not fit their idea of "material"

Comment: a glass cannot be bent or folded, I think their "Material" is defined by rigid objects not stuff like paper or cardboard. more like a glass with nano technology which can change its geometry and change size and with jets to elevate but cannot simply fold themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please leave comment when you down vote the question.

Comment: They may say that it never bends or folds, but it doesn't appear to apply to them: in several of the introductory videos, (e.g., "Making Material Design" - http://www.google.com/design/videos/making-material-design/ and "Crafting Material" - http://www.google.com/design/videos/crafting-material/) they quite prominently feature folded items: the gmail and gcal icons are both shown being made by folding, and appear in a number of shots showing how light interacts with a folded object.

Answer (score 8):

Just a note to other answerers: 
If something is a certain way just because they "say so", you are following horrible design. Good and proper design has meaning and purpose to every rule. This is otherwise misrepresentation. Just because someone says "we are about design", doesn't mean it's true. ;)

Why does Google say that material does not bend and fold? For the same reason that they say "Material is not necessarily flat, though it removes unneeded complexity" and that "animations are there to show where things are on screen" among other similar phrases.

They want everything on screen to have meaning - to have purpose. This is very much so the mentality of MD and a very large reason why many things are the way that they are.

Think of it this way - my mother does not know how to use technology. I've been trying to move her to Lollipop because of this reason, MD - when done properly - is designed so that the user can figure out things on their own without instruction because of cues and natural habits in one's brain (see Egoraptor's Megaman Sequalitis for a decent understanding of what I mean). This allows the user to feel smarter than if you shove them in front of an non-understandable system with an instruction book and cuts out that middle man. By adding folds and bends, you are adding symbolism where there does not need to be. If a fold is done a certain way you can misdirect someone, have their attention elsewhere. The idea is to design for meaning - not for complexity.

Comment: I think you start well, talking about purposeful design and "not necessarily"s, and "cues and natural habits in one's brain", but then you claim that folds and bends are never necessary or useful symbolism.

While I can appreciate that it's worth challenging the actual need for those, I wouldn't go as far as to say that they wouldn't be useful in any circumstance. And indeed according to @Cagentdog's answer, Google themselves have recognized the value of such exceptions where it makes sense, e.g. in Google Play Books.

Comment: Alas, that's me just being lazy, cutting off at the end as I ran out of time (as I had to head off to work). What I mean to say here - is not that folds and bends are never useful for symbolism, but rather that they can be overly powerful for symbolism. You have to be careful with such and I think that is why that Google is sticking to the fact that they don't want misuse of such. I tried to make that point in my comment but I suppose I was not clear. They just want to ovoid unneeded symbolism when possible, for example (I know many here are involved with Papyros) - many of those mockups are a

Comment: great example of how folding and bending can go overboard and ruin an otherwise purpose-filled design. Notice how Google Play Books only uses one fold and they do so accordingly as it is a needed complexity - to clarify that it is a bookmark of a kind (if I recall correctly). Otherwise I may have a hard time understanding what the symbolism there (see, me giving credit to such ;D). The main point here isn't that Material NEVER folds, but to designers who simply follow guidelines without thinking of overarching design choices, they should be avoided is what I am more or less understanding

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of an explanation provided by Google, but here is my speculation.

I suspect it relates to

> Material casts shadows.

and

> Shadows are never approximated by coloring material.

And allowing material to bend or fold would make shadowing significantly more complex to render.
If a material could bend the distance between the shadowed material and the shadowing material would not be constant and thus may be quiet difficult to render.

Comment: A fair point, but I'm not sure whether technical feasibility plays much of a part here.

Answer (score 0):

> Z-axis motion is typically a result of user interaction with material.

And to my mind it means "reserved" to it.

So for me bending and folding are pure graphical (aesthetically) animation and so should not use the Z-axis

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: cuz google says so

Long answer: I guess we won't ever know what's going on in Google's collective head but I believe @attif farrukh is correct. Google says material isn't paper its a paper thin rigid substance of some kind. Google play books still has folding pages and their thing is: "be together not the same" so I guess you're allowed to break the rules.